# Refactoring class component to function component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have class component now I want to convert it to function component so I started with refactoring constructor

here is my class component

```
class EventCalendar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            today: this.getToday(),
        };         
    }

    getToday() {
        var today = new Date();
        return {
            day: today.getDate(),
            month: today.getMonth(),
            year: today.getFullYear(),
        };
    }

       renderCalendarDays() {
        return this.getDaysWithEvents().map((day, index) => {
            const isToday = Calendar.interval(day, this.state.today) === 1;            
            return (
                <CalendarDay 
                    day={day} 
                    isToday={isToday} 
                    />
                );
        });
    }

      render() {

        return (
                {this.renderCalendarDays()}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Here is my refactored functional component from class

```
const EventCalendar =props=> {

const [today, setToday] = useState();
const calendar = new Calendar({siblingMonths: true, });

useEffect(() => {
   setToday();
},[])

const  setToday =()=>{
    var today = new Date();
    return {
        day: today.getDate(),
        month: today.getMonth(),
        year: today.getFullYear(),
    };
}
  const  renderCalendarDays = ()=>{
        return getDaysWithEvents().map((day, index) => {
            const isToday = Calendar.interval(day, today) === 1;
            return (
                <CalendarDay 
                    day={day} 
                    isToday={isToday} 

                    />
                );
        });
    }

        return (
            <div className="flexContainer">
                {renderCalendarDays()}
            </div>
        );
}
```

Unfortunately, I am struggling to make this work, can someone help me, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You actually have two `setToday` methods.  In `useEffect`, you want to call something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   ...
   setToday(createToday());
   ...
},{})
```

```
createToday = () => {
    const today = new Date();
    return {
        day: today.getDate(),
        month: today.getMonth(),
        year: today.getFullYear(),
    };
}
```

Right now, when you call `setToday()` in `useEffect`, I honestly do not know if you are setting the state variable, `today` to `null` or you are calling your helper method, returning an object, but not assigning it.

Also, keep in mind `useEffect` is for side effects (hence the name), such as reaching out to services, doing asynchronous sorts of things, etc.

You could skip the `useEffect` and just run `createToday` in your state defintion:

```
const [today, setToday] = useState(createToday());
```

An example of how I might do this:

```
const createToday =()=>{
    const today = new Date();
    return {
        day: today.getDate(),
        month: today.getMonth(),
        year: today.getFullYear(),
    };
}


const EventCalendar = (/*no props yet*/)=> {

const [today, setToday] = useState(createToday());
const calendar = new Calendar({siblingMonths: true, });

const renderCalendarDays = () => getDaysWithEvents().map((day, index) => {
        const isToday = Calendar.interval(day, today) === 1;
        return (
            <CalendarDay 
                day={day} 
                isToday={isToday} 

                />
            );
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className="flexContainer">
            {renderCalendarDays()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi West Now I am getting this error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of undefined`

Comment: I'm not sure what your code looks like at this point.  Maybe focus on the `useState` part, get rid of everything else, and just render `<>{today}</>` to make sure that much is working.  Just a suggestion to start small.

Comment: now I get this the following error : `×
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'createToday' before initialization`

Comment: ha, yeah that would be true if you are defining `useState` before defining `const createToday`.    Since `createToday` is independent of your React component, you could just define it above the React component definition. Then it will be there when you run the component.

Comment: I updated the answer to give you more of a working version.